# How to cut a string and put it onto the next line

Tags: tcl

I have created a tcl policy and my last line is a long String as follows;

```
set tpl_def(0) "$displacement_tpl_def~$pressure_tpl_def~$vibration_tpl_def~$temperature_tpl_def~$load_tpl_def~idling_tpl_def~miles_gallon_tpl_def~engine_temp_tpl_def~engine_speed_tpl_def~accelerator_position_tpl_def~vehicle_speed_tpl_def~miles_per_gallon_tpl_def~engine_intake_manifold_pressure_tpl_def~engine_intake_manifold_temp_tpl_def~vehicle_speed_mph_tpl_def"
```

Now when I try to run this policy my router cuts off the String about two thirds of the way through. Is there a way that I can cut the string and continue it on the next line?

For example like Java, you would do something like this;

```
set tpl_def(0) "$displacement_tpl_def~$pressure_tpl_def~$vibration_tpl_def~$temperature_tpl_def~$load_tpl_"
+"def~idling_tpl_def~miles_gallon_tpl_def~engine_temp_tpl_def~engine_speed_tpl_def~accelerator_position_tpl_def~vehicle_speed_tpl_def~"
+ "miles_per_gallon_tpl_def~engine_intake_manifold_pressure_tpl_def~engine_intake_manifold_temp_tpl_def~vehicle_speed_mph_tpl_def"
```

Is there a way I could do something similar in tcl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use line continuations, but that will inserts a space into the string in place of the backslash-newline-whitespace.

```
set tpl_def(0) "$displacement_tpl_def~$pressure_tpl_def~$vibration_tpl_def~$temperature_tpl_def~\
$load_tpl_def~idling_tpl_def~miles_gallon_tpl_def~engine_temp_tpl_def~\
engine_speed_tpl_def~accelerator_position_tpl_def~vehicle_speed_tpl_def~\
miles_per_gallon_tpl_def~engine_intake_manifold_pressure_tpl_def~\
engine_intake_manifold_temp_tpl_def~vehicle_speed_mph_tpl_def"
```

[`append`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/append.htm) is what you want:

```
append tpl_def(0) \
    "$displacement_tpl_def~$pressure_tpl_def~$vibration_tpl_def~$temperature_tpl_def~" \
    "$load_tpl_def~idling_tpl_def~miles_gallon_tpl_def~engine_temp_tpl_def~" \
    "engine_speed_tpl_def~accelerator_position_tpl_def~vehicle_speed_tpl_def~" \
    "miles_per_gallon_tpl_def~engine_intake_manifold_pressure_tpl_def~" \
    "engine_intake_manifold_temp_tpl_def~vehicle_speed_mph_tpl_def"
```

Comment: The other way is to make a list and then `join $theList "~"`…